# How to use addAll with generic collection?

Tags: java

Why does

```
List<Map<String, Object>> a, b;
a.addAll(b);
```

compile

But

```
List<? extends Map<String, ?>> a, b;
a.addAll(b);
```

does not.

How to make the latter compile?

Comment: Exchange `? extends Map<String, ?>` for a type that extends `Map<String, Object>`because when declaring variables you need to give them a type. If not you need to use interfaces like in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that `CustomHashMap` extends `HashMap` and you initialize `a` like following:

```
List<CustomHashMap<String, String> list = new ArrayList<CustomHashMap<String, String>>();
List<? extends Map<String, ?>> a = list;
```

if you were able to to add entries to `a`...

```
a.add(new HashMap<String, String>());
```

...you would encounter this strange situation

```
CustomHashMap<String, String> map = list.get(0); // you would expect to get CustomHashMap object but you will get a HashMap object instead
```

In other words, you don't know the actual type of you Map (when you say ? extends Map), everything you know is that it is a some subtype of Map and you can not add arbitrary objects to the List because you need to ensure that there is a supertype for the added object. But you can't since the exact type of the Map is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add items to a wildcard generic list. The first one compiles because it has a defined type.

You may, however, find some super class that suits your purpose and use it as generic argument.

**UPDATE:**

see also [Wildcard (in the Oracle docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: Why doesn't this compile either?

    `List<? extends Map<String, ?>> a;`
    `List<Map<String, Object>> b;`
    `a.addAll(b);`

Comment: It is, again, because you'd be adding items to your wildcard generic collection `a`.

Comment: Because you try to add in a Collection defined with wildcard and that is not allowed in Java.

Comment: @arjacsoh Note that Collection can be added if defined with `? super` wild card

Comment: Of course in a Collection<? super T> elements excusively of Type T can be added, but the question concerns wildcard with extends.

Answer (score 1):

According [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) you can declare helper method in this case (ugly but works):

```
static <T extends List<K>, V, K extends Map<String, V>> void addAllHelper(T from, T to) {
        from.addAll(to);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you declare it with concrete Generic Type, it compiles. If you define a class:

```
public class AClass<T extends Map<String, ?>> {

    public List<T> dostuff() {

        List<T> lista = new ArrayList<T>();
        List<T> listb = new ArrayList<T>();

        lista.addAll(listb);
        return lista;
    }
}
```

With wildcards it cannot compile.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using a method like:

```
private <S extends Map<String, ?>> void method(List<S> a, List<S> b){
    a.addAll(b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code should help you explain this

`List<? super Number>` a is called `out` parameter and can be used for updates
`List<? extends Number> b` is called `in` parameter and can be used to read

Commented lines below results in compilation error for the reason as mentioned in comments

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    addAll(numberList, intList);
    addAll(numberList, doubleList);
    addAll(intList, doubleList);//cant add double to int
    addAll(doubleList,intList);//cant add int double
    addAll(intList, numberList);//cant add number to int
}

private static<T> void addAll(List<? super T> a, List<? extends T> b) {
    a.addAll(b);
}
```